# SQL query to retrieve the data in the following format

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
input               col1                col2
---------------------------------------------------------
12/8/2018 1:45      12/8/2018 1:45      12/8/2018 11:03
12/8/2018 11:03     12/8/2018 11:03     12/11/2018 13:26
12/11/2018 13:26    12/11/2018 13:26    12/13/2018 17:21
12/13/2018 17:21    12/13/2018 17:21    12/23/2018 17:21
12/23/2018 17:21    12/23/2018 17:21    12/24/2018 16:17
12/24/2018 16:17    12/24/2018 16:17    12/24/2018 16:17
```

I'm trying to create columns **col1** and **col2** using **input** column based the logic below:

1. Each value of **col1** is same as input column
2. Each value of **col2** is (`input + 1`) row.
3. The last row will have both **col1** and **col2** values as same.

I'm trying to implement the logic in a SQL query to get the **col1** and **col2** columns based on the logic above. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Questions:

1. Where is the `input` data coming from?

2. Any sample SQL query you have tried that fails to do what you want done?

Comment: Why do you expect col2 last entry to have a date time shouldn't it be null since there is no new inputs after 12/24/2018 16:17?  Basically you don't have an end point to the last entry time.

Comment: Does point 2 make sense though? What's `(input + 1) row`? Does that mean adding *1 year, 1 month, 1 day, 1 hour or 1 minute* to the value in col1?

Answer (score 3):

The LEAD analytical function was created for this:

```
SELECT
  input,
  input as col1,
  COALESCE(LEAD(input) OVER(ORDER BY input), input) as col2
FROM table
```

Lead returns the given value from the "next" row, the meaning of "next" being deduced from the ORDER BY clause. Lead can additionally take a number argument if you want the value that is 2, 3, N rows ahead

I've made the assumption that your ordering is in ascending order of the date that `input` is but if you want something hing else to define the order of the rows, put it in the "order by" inside the "over"

Lead will return null on the last row, so I coalesce the input value to meet your spec. Lead does have an optional parameter of what value to use from the current row if there is no row at the offset, I just tend not to use it as I find it less readable. `LEAD(input, 3, othercol)` means "give the value of input from 3 rows ahead, or give othercol if there is no row. Othercol can be any column from the row, even `input` again

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do what you want using window functions:

```
select input, input as col1,
       lead(input, 1, input) over (order by input) as col2
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your *point number 2* is unclear and I have assumed it here that you want to add 1 day to the *value of **input*** to create something for `col2`.

Here is one way you can do it:

```
SELECT input, input AS col1, (
  CASE
     WHEN id != (SELECT MAX(id) FROM <table_name>) /** last item assumed to have the highest id */
      THEN
        input + INTERVAL '1 day'
      ELSE
        input
  END
  ) AS col2
FROM <table_name>;
```